# Eloquent push() and save() difference

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have read laravel 4 docs about eloquent and was quite intrigued by the push() part.
It says,

> Sometimes you may wish to save not only a model, but also all of its relationships. To do so, you may use the push method:
>
> Saving A Model And Relationships
>
> `$user->push();`

[See link here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Sorry but it's a bit blurry on my part the difference between save() and push().
I am hoping someone can clear this one out for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Heres the magic behind the scenes...

```
/**
 * Save the model and all of its relationships.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function push()
{
    if ( ! $this->save()) return false;

    // To sync all of the relationships to the database, we will simply spin through
    // the relationships and save each model via this "push" method, which allows
    // us to recurse into all of these nested relations for the model instance.

    foreach ($this->relations as $models)
    {
        foreach (Collection::make($models) as $model)
        {
            if ( ! $model->push()) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

It just shows that `push()` will update all the models related to the model in question, so if you change any of the relationships, then call `push()`
It will update that model, and all its relations
Like so...

```
$user = User::find(32);
$user->name = "TestUser";
$user->state = "Texas";
$user->location->address = "123 test address"; //This line is a pre-defined relationship
```

If here you just...

```
$user->save();
```

Then the address wont be saved into the address model....
But if you..

```
$user->push();
```

Then it will save all the data, and also save the address into the address `table/model`, because you defined that relationship in the `User model`.

`push()` will also update all the updated_at timestamps of all related models of whatever user/model you `push()`

Hopefully that will clear the things....

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I just have one issue... About this line:
`$user->state->address = "123 test address"; //This line is a pre-defined relationship`
What do you mean by this? Is this the same as the relationship you define in eloquent like ->hasOne() ?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean  :)  The hasOne() class extends the Relations class....those are the relations eloquent looks at when it does its push() feature... as can be seen on the line in the code above......foreach ($this->relations as $models)

Comment: Thanks Kyle... I just noticed that it won't push() if the related model has no entry on the database.

Comment: the `->state` / `->state->address` assignment doesn't make sense. Your example shows `->state` on `$user` is a string, not a relationship.

Comment: hi @Kylie excellent answer +1. then `push()` "by default" only saves the "direct" relationships of a model, but thanks to the "recursive" iteration that `push()` does (behind the scenes) it manages to save the nested relationships of a model as well, right?

Comment: that is, no matter **how nested** the relationships are, right? @Kylie

Answer (score 46):

Let's say you did this:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->phone = '555-0101';
$user->address->zip_code = '99950';
```

You just made changes to two different tables, to save them you have to:

```
$user->save();
$user->address->save();
```

or

```
$user->push();
```

Comment: @Antonio what about if use push() to insert new relational record instead of edit current record ? is it possible ? thanks in advance.

Comment: what if I instantiated $user = new User()  and  $address = new Address(),  and assign $address to $user->address. will push() save both ?

Comment: It seems, push() does not work with new records. See this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4641

Answer (score 4):

push() can only be used to update an existing model instance along side its relations not to create a new one. Simply say: push() updates and not insert.

Comment: This is not true.