# how to use Laravel Eloquent push() function?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am struggling to use laravel `push()` function

My Code is here:

```
$company = new Company(array('name' => 'Company 1'));
$company->persons[] = new Person(array('name' => 'Company 1 Person 1', 'mobile' => 12345));
$company->persons[] = new Person(array('name' => 'Company 1 Person 2', 'mobile' => 112233));
$company->push();
```

When it gets stored:
Company gets stored well, but for company persons, it stores `company_id` to `0`

Larave Documentations says:

> Sometimes you may wish to save not only a model, but also all of its
>   relationships. To do so, you may use the push method:

```
$user->push();
```

what is wrong?

Comment: I've never used `push()` before but it seems like maybe you aren't using it correctly. The docs don't give much mention to it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035682/eloquent-push-and-save-difference)

Comment: I have a feeling that push will only work with pre-defined relationships, not creating new records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not Doctrine ;)

`push` could do it, BUT it wouldn't be nice and easy (below you can find out how)

And here's what you can do instead (**nice and easy way**):

```
// still you need already existing Company, so save it first
$company = new Company(array('name' => 'Company 1'));
$company->save();

$company->persons()->createMany(array(
  array('name' => 'Company 1 Person 1', 'mobile' => 12345),
  array('name' => 'Company 1 Person 2', 'mobile' => 12345)
));
```

This will save new `Person` models and associate them with the `Company`

---

`push` would do the job, but only if you do it with already existing parent AND you first associate child models:

```
$company = Company::first(); // or any existing

$person = new Person(array('name' => 'Company 1 Person 1', 'mobile' => 12345));
$person->company()->associate($company);

$anotherPerson = new Person(array('name' => 'Company 1 Person 2', 'mobile' => 12345));
$anotherPerson->company()->associate($company);

$company->persons[] = $person;
$company->persons[] = $anotherPerson
$company->push();
```

**Obviously this is more work and it's definitely not the way I would suggest.**

Comment: @decoz, then don't you agree that the line written in doc is very confusing? They say "you may wish to save not only a model, but also all of its relationships"???

Comment: I'm not going to argue with that. However, to be precise, Eloquent is saving those models, only it doesn't associate them with the relation parent, which is obviously unexpected. Like I said, it's not Doctrine. It handles relations differently, sometimes you'd expect more from it, but that's how it works currently.

Comment: ha ha ah!!! sure second method is not at all preferred. In short `push()` can be used only with existing one. I didn't know `createMany` method. Thanks!

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk very usefull your answer. I have a question, if I call in your first example $company->persons it will be lazy loaded?, I mean will query the DB or it is in memory?