# Laravel Save data one to one relationships with push()?

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4

Terms table:

- term_id
- name
- slug

Term_taxonomy table:

- term_taxonomy_id
- term_id
- description

My Term model:

```
public function TermTaxonomy(){
    return $this->hasOne('TermTaxonomy');
}

public function saveCategory($data){
    $validator = Validator::make($data,$this->rules);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $this->name = $data['name'];
        $this->slug = $data['slug'];
        $this->save();
        $TermTaxonomy = new TermTaxonomy;
        $TermTaxonomy->taxonomy = 'category';
        $TermTaxonomy->description = $data['TermTaxonomy']['description'];
        if($this->TermTaxonomy()->save($TermTaxonomy)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        }else{
                return false;
        }
    }else{
        $this->errors = $validator;
        return false;
    } 
}
```

My TermTaxonomy model:

```
public function Term(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Term');
}
```

I have read Laravel 4 docs inserting related models

> Sometimes you may wish to save not only a model, but also all of its relationships. To do so, you may use the push method:
>
> Saving A Model And Relationships
>
> `$user->push();`

[See link here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Then I read @Antonio Carlos Answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035682/eloquent-push-and-save-difference) he says it can replace 2 `save()` syntax with `push()`, I think this good way because less code.

in my `saveCategory()` method it work like expected , but I want to know how I can use `push()` in my `saveCategory()` method? Already google that but nothing.

I am new in Laravel and any help will be appreciated.