# Laravel saving hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, ardent

I'm using Laravel & Ardent and having issues saving through the hasMany relationship.

I have two classes.

Workorder:

```
protected   $table          = 'workorder';
protected   $primaryKey     = 'workorder_id';
public static $relationsData = [
    'dates'         => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'App\WorkOrderDate', 'foreignKey' => 'workorder_id'),
];
```

WorkOrderDate:

```
protected   $table          = 'workorder_date';
protected   $primaryKey     = 'date_id';
public static $relationsData = array(
    'workorder'  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'App\WorkOrder')
);
```

after saving my Workorder (which works fine), I'm trying to save a collection of Date models by executing:

```
$workorder->dates()->saveMany($myDateCollection->all());
```

But it's not running the date insert, and it's not giving me any errors.  I turned on query logging and it looks like Laravel is trying to run an update instead of an insert.  Do I have my relationship defined incorrectly here?

Comment: Im not sure if this is still the case in L5....but back in L3 and 4 I remember that whenever I wanted to save to a relationship, I had to create it first.  Only then would pushing an update to the relationship work.  It was a wierd bug.  I wrote an answer a while ago which goes over the push code, and you can see that it will only save if the relationship already has a corresponding entry.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035682/eloquent-push-and-save-difference/17035768#17035768  but again, L5 might be completely different.  Just thought Id point that out

Comment: That would be super confusing, since the docs note the saveMany method under the heading "Inserting Related Models": https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: also what is $myDateCollection->all() returning. an array? collection of models?

Comment: $myDateCollection is a collection of WorkOrderDate models.  Collection->all() returns an array of models.

Comment: I only see the saveMany() method in the  BelongsToMany, or HasOneOrMany  classes in L5 relations. Not in the BelongsTo or HasMany.  Maybe that has something to do with it?? I dont really know, just pointing it out

Comment: HasMany extends HasOneOrMany

Comment: haha... My brain isnt cooperating today. duuuuuh lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hydrating my date collection from user input, and when you hydrate a model, Laravel assumes the model exists already.  Turns out this is not what I mean to do.

More detail here:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9360